# Is it possible to create a discriminated union via a unit of measure tag in F#?

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement, discriminated-union

Is it possible to create a discriminated union type via a unit of measurement tag in F#?

I want to write sth. like the following:

```
type DomainObject =
| Pixel           of int
| ScaledPixel     of int
| Centimeter      of float
| Unset

let var1 = 10<px> // should equal: let var1 = Pixel(10)
let var2 = 0<us>  // should equal: let var2 = Unset

let process sth =
  match sth with
  | Pixel(p) -> ...
  | Centimeter(c) -> ...
  // etc.
```

With NumericLiterals such things are possible. But then one can only use a small amount of Literals like [Neil P. showed](http://techneilogy.blogspot.de/2011/07/f-user-defined-numeric-literals.html).

Comment: The simple answer is: No.

Comment: Is there any other way to create custom suffix operators in F#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the simple answer is no.

In a way, you are trying to misuse one F# feature (units of measure) to emulate a feature that might exist in other languages (suffix operators), which is probably a bad thing to do in the first place, because (even if it was possible), the resulting code would be quite confusing.

If you simply want to reverse the order of the arguments so that the number comes before the unit name, you can use the piping operator and write:

```
let var1 = 10 |> Pixel
let var2 = Unset
```

This essentially gives you a way to write "suffix operators", but using standard F# idioms.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this special combination is possible but you can go with smart constructors if you like:

```
module Domain =

    [<Measure>] type px
    [<Measure>] type spx
    [<Measure>] type cm
    // ...


    type DomainObject =
    | Pixel           of float<px>
    | ScaledPixel     of float<spx>
    | Centimeter      of float<cm>
    | Unset

    let inline pixel f = Pixel <| float f * 1.0<px>
    let inline scaledPixel f = ScaledPixel <| float f * 1.0<spx>
    let unset = Unset
    // ...

    let var1 = pixel 10
    let var2 = unset

    let process sth =
      match sth with
      | Pixel(p) -> ...
      | Centimeter(c) -> ...
      // etc.
```

I think this is reasonable close - if you want you can make the constructors private and add active-patterns (to reenable pattern-matching) or accessors to fully encapsulate the implementation-details.

If you get fancy you can even add `(+)`, `(-)`, ...

PS: the inline is to get the functions working with all kinds of numeric values ;)

PPS: I played a bit and the problem is indeed (as mentioned in the link you gave - that you can only have a very limited set of "suffixes" - namely `Q, R, Z, I, N, and G`) - for example this kindof works:

```
module NumericLiteralQ =
  open Domain

  let inline FromZero() = Pixel 0.0<px>
  let inline FromOne() = Pixel 1.0<px>
  let inline FromString (s:string) =
      System.Double.Parse s * 1.0<px> |> Pixel
  let inline FromInt32 (n:int) =
      1.0<px> * float n |> Pixel
  let inline FromInt64 (n:int64) = 
      1.0<px> * float n |> Pixel
```

but I think it's very uggly to write

```
let p = 5Q
```

instead of

```
let p = pixel 5
```

or

```
let p = 5 |> pixel
```

Comment: This isn't actually what I was looking for. I don't see much benefit in writing:  `let var1 = pixel 10` instead of `let var1 = Pixel 10`. I was looking for a suffix version like it is with NumericLiterals, where one could write `let var1 = 10Z` where `Z` would result in a c'tor call.

Comment: well sorry, as I said: I don't see any way to do this the way you want. But this was to much for comments (unreadable, I tried) - want me to remove the answer?

Comment: PS: I thought maybe you want the type-safety you get with the units-of-measure

Comment: No your answer is fine. Just isn't the silver-bullet-solution that I was dreaming of. Please don't remove it as source for inspiration for others ;-)